# Distance calculation based on multiple locations (Lat,Lon) including starting/ finishing point

Tags: php, distance

I would like to calculate the total distance of driving beetween multiple locations (loop), including the distance (starting point (garage) - first location sarting point) and (last location finishig point - finishing point (garage)).
Example:
(Garage + D1) + (D1 + D2) + (D2 + E1) + (E1 + E2) + E2 + Garage)

I'm having a problem with the correct looping. Here's my simplified code:

```
<?
$driver = 5;

     $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='$driver' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
     while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
         $lon=$row2['lon'];
         $lat=$row2['lat'];
    echo "$lon, $lat";
     }

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE driver='$driver'") or die(mysql_error());  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

         $lon1=$row['lon1'];
         $lat1=$row['lat1'];
         $lon2=$row['lon2'];
         $lat2=$row['lat2'];

        //////////  distance between driver address and starting address    
        $distancecalc = (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat-$lat1)*($lat-$lat1) + cos($lat/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon-$lon1)*($lon-$lon1))/180);
        //////////  distance between statring address and finishing address  - multiple adsresses
        $distancecalc1 = $distancecalc1 + (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);
        //////////  distance between finishing address and driver address
        $distancecalc2 = (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat)*($lat2-$lat) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon)*($lon2-$lon))/180);

        $distancetotal = $distancecalc + $distancecalc1 +$distancecalc2;

        echo "$distancecalc<br>
        $distancecalc1<br>
        $distancecalc2<br>";
    }
    echo "$distancetotal";
  ?>
```

I tried some things (mostly if... ) and also with more database requests, but I'm still having the problem of avoiding multiple calculations, and I also strongly believe there is way to code it to make it easier and clearer.

I would appreciate some help on this one.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could write a function `distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)`. You could also do the entire thing in a single SQL join between the two tables, with the calculations in the `SELECT` statement. You can create a user-defined `DISTANCE()` function in SQL to shorten it.

Comment: That is already good starting point .. but bring it to life is anothers story will be nice to have some code examples ... will look into it

Comment: Your total calculation doesn't seem right. You're accumulating `$distancecalc1` and `$distancecalc2` each time through the loop, but `$distancecalc` is not accumulating. And you don't need to assign `$distancetotal` each time, you're not using it in the loop. If the other three variables are cumulative, you can add them together at the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I worked it out with help of mac_gyver (php freaks). All calculations are done as i wish.  My code below:

```
<?
include "connectdb.php";
$driver = 5;
$datestamp = '2013/05/07';
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE id='$driver' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
         $lon=$row2['lon'];
         $lat=$row2['lat'];
     }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotedb WHERE moveday='$datestamp' AND driver='$driver' AND cleared='Not Cleared' AND status='Done' ORDER BY moveday, timeday") or die(mysql_error());  
    $distance = 0; // accumulate the distance
    $first_pass = true;  // flag to detect the first row inside the loop
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
         $lon2a=$lon2;
         $lat2a=$lat2;
         $lon1=$row['lon1'];
         $lat1=$row['lat1'];
         $lon2=$row['lon2'];
         $lat2=$row['lat2'];
         // calculate the distance from the Garage to the first point of the first row
    if($first_pass){
        $distance += (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat-$lat1)*($lat-$lat1) + cos($lat/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon-$lon1)*($lon-$lon1))/180);
        $first_pass = false;
    }
    // calculate the distance for each row (segment) in the route
    $distance += (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);
    if ( $lon2a == "" or $lat2a =="" ) {            
        } else {
        // calculate the distance from the second point of the first row to the first point of the next row 
    $distance += (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2a-$lat1)*($lat2a-$lat1) + cos($lat2a/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2a-$lon1)*($lon2a-$lon1))/180);
        }
    }
    // calculate the distance from the second point of the last row to the Garage
    $distance += (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat)*($lat2-$lat) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon)*($lon2-$lon))/180);
echo "$distance<br>
";
  ?>
```

Still think there is a place for improvement in the code. Will aplay Haversine method for calculations. Do you guys have some suggestion to improve this piece of code ... thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function you need:

```
function distance ($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    return (3958*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180);
}
```

The function body is exactly the same as the formula you used in-line, so I don't understand why you needed help with this.

Comment: as i mentioned at the beggining what needs to be calculated is distance between starting point (garage with constant lat , lon - which is also a finishing point) to first destination (starting point). And there are multiple locations to go in a meanwhile. And then driver has to make his way back to garage from last destination to garage. Example for let say two of them. (Garage + D1) + (D1 + D2) + (D2 + E1) + (E1 + E2) + E2 + Garage). I have to loop it. i still do not know how ??

Answer (score 0):

The number 6367 - is the radius of the Earth in kilometers

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geodist $$
CREATE FUNCTION geodist (
  src_lat DECIMAL(9,6), src_lon DECIMAL(9,6),
  dst_lat DECIMAL(9,6), dst_lon DECIMAL(9,6)
) RETURNS DECIMAL(6,2) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 SET @dist := 6367 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
      POWER(SIN((src_lat - ABS(dst_lat)) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) +
      COS(src_lat * PI()/180) *
      COS(ABS(dst_lat) * PI()/180) *
      POWER(SIN((src_lon - dst_lon) * PI()/180 / 2), 2)
    ));
 RETURN @dist;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Impoved version:

```
<?
include "connectdb.php";
$driver = 5;
$datestamp = '2013/05/07';
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE id='$driver' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
         $garage_lon=$row2['lon'];
         $garage_lat=$row2['lat'];
     }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotedb WHERE moveday='$datestamp' AND driver='$driver' AND cleared='Not Cleared' AND status='Done' ORDER BY moveday, timeday") or die(mysql_error());  

    function calculate_distance($lon1, $lat1, $lon2, $lat2) {
    return (3958 * 3.1415926 * sqrt(($lat2 - $lat1) * ($lat2 - $lat1) + cos($lat2 / 57.29578) * cos($lat1 / 57.29578) * ($lon2 - $lon1) * ($lon2 - $lon1)) / 180);}  

$previous_lon = $garage_lon;
$previous_lat = $garage_lat;
$distance = 0; // accumulate the distance

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
{
    $lon1 = $row['lon1'];
    $lat1 = $row['lat1'];
    $lon2 = $row['lon2'];
    $lat2 = $row['lat2'];
    if ( $previous_lon && $previous_lat )
    {
        // calculate the distance from the second point of the first row to the first point of the next row 
        $distance += calculate_distance($lon1, $lat1, $previous_lon, $previous_lat);
    }
    // calculate the distance for each row (segment) in the route
    $distance += calculate_distance($lon1, $lat1, $lon2, $lat2);
    $previous_lon = $lon2;
    $previous_lat = $lat2;
}
// calculate the distance from the second point of the last row to the Garage
$distance += calculate_distance($garage_lon, $garage_lat, $lon2, $lat2);  
    $distance = round($distance,0);
echo "$distance<br>
";
  ?>
```